# Pandas LTM sum with duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to compute the rolling sum of the last 12 months of a numerical column that's grouped by an entity ID. My data looks somewhat like this:

```
    eID    perioddate  123456  
14  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0 
74  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0 
35  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0 
96  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0 
57  ABC    2011-04-30  11209.0 
18  ABC    2011-04-30  11209.0 
81  ABC    2011-07-31  11451.0 
44  ABC    2011-07-31  11451.0 
07  ABC    2011-07-31  11451.0 
70  ABC    2011-10-31  20062.0 
34  ABC    2011-10-31  20062.0 
98  ABC    2011-10-31  20062.0 
62  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0 
26  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0 
90  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0 
56  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0 
24  ABC    2012-04-30  41799.0 
92  ABC    2012-04-30  41799.0 
60  ABC    2012-07-31  41874.0 
28  ABC    2012-07-31  41874.0 
99  ABC    2012-07-31  41874.0 
69  ABC    2012-10-31  46783.0
```

And I want each row to have the rolling sum as long as there is at least a full year of history, so my resulting new column would look like this:

```
    eID    perioddate  123456  123456_ltm
14  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0        
74  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0        
35  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0        
96  ABC    2011-01-31  31773.0        
57  ABC    2011-04-30  11209.0        
18  ABC    2011-04-30  11209.0        
81  ABC    2011-07-31  11451.0        
44  ABC    2011-07-31  11451.0        
07  ABC    2011-07-31  11451.0        
70  ABC    2011-10-31  20062.0   74495.0      
34  ABC    2011-10-31  20062.0   74495.0      
98  ABC    2011-10-31  20062.0   74495.0      
62  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0   85234.0      
26  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0   85234.0
90  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0   85234.0
56  ABC    2012-01-31  42512.0   85234.0
24  ABC    2012-04-30  41799.0  115824.0      
92  ABC    2012-04-30  41799.0  115824.0      
60  ABC    2012-07-31  41874.0  146247.0      
28  ABC    2012-07-31  41874.0  146247.0
99  ABC    2012-07-31  41874.0  146247.0
69  ABC    2012-10-31  46783.0  172968.0
```

From similar questions I've tried the following:

```py
fx = lambda x: x.rolling(4).sum()
df[id + '_ltm'] = df.groupby(['eID','perioddate'])[id].apply(fx)
```

Unfortunately I just get NaN from the above. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: You say you want a full year, but the count starts from october...?

Comment: The data points themselves are quarterly sums, so the 1/31/11 number would include data back to 10/31/10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a groupby is unnecessary here, unless I'm missing something. All you need is a `rolling` `sum` + `merge`.

```
v = df.set_index('perioddate')\
        .drop_duplicates()['123456'].rolling(4).sum().to_frame()

v

              123456
perioddate          
2011-01-31       NaN
2011-04-30       NaN
2011-07-31       NaN
2011-10-31   74495.0
2012-01-31   85234.0
2012-04-30  115824.0
2012-07-31  146247.0
2012-10-31  172968.0

df.merge(v, left_on='perioddate', right_index=True)

    eID perioddate  123456_x  123456_y
14  ABC 2011-01-31   31773.0       NaN
74  ABC 2011-01-31   31773.0       NaN
35  ABC 2011-01-31   31773.0       NaN
96  ABC 2011-01-31   31773.0       NaN
57  ABC 2011-04-30   11209.0       NaN
18  ABC 2011-04-30   11209.0       NaN
81  ABC 2011-07-31   11451.0       NaN
44  ABC 2011-07-31   11451.0       NaN
7   ABC 2011-07-31   11451.0       NaN
70  ABC 2011-10-31   20062.0   74495.0
34  ABC 2011-10-31   20062.0   74495.0
98  ABC 2011-10-31   20062.0   74495.0
62  ABC 2012-01-31   42512.0   85234.0
26  ABC 2012-01-31   42512.0   85234.0
90  ABC 2012-01-31   42512.0   85234.0
56  ABC 2012-01-31   42512.0   85234.0
24  ABC 2012-04-30   41799.0  115824.0
92  ABC 2012-04-30   41799.0  115824.0
60  ABC 2012-07-31   41874.0  146247.0
28  ABC 2012-07-31   41874.0  146247.0
99  ABC 2012-07-31   41874.0  146247.0
69  ABC 2012-10-31   46783.0  172968.0
```

---

Edit: If you need the `groupby`, you can move everything into a `dfGroupBy.apply` call:

```
v = df.set_index('perioddate').groupby('eID', group_keys=False)\
          .apply(lambda x: x.drop_duplicates()['123456'].rolling(4).sum()).T

v

eID              ABC
perioddate          
2011-01-31       NaN
2011-04-30       NaN
2011-07-31       NaN
2011-10-31   74495.0
2012-01-31   85234.0
2012-04-30  115824.0
2012-07-31  146247.0
2012-10-31  172968.0
```

The `merge` step remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, Coldspeed! The groupby's are because there are many different entities (denoted by eID) and I need to sum within them. Each one can also have different period dates (e.g. one might be Jan/Apr/Jul/Oct, another might be Mar/Jun/Sep/Dec). So perhaps I only need to groupby eID and not both?

Comment: @rgk yeah, if you do a groupby on eID and then do the same thing, you should get what you really need.

Comment: Thanks again, was eventually able to get it working. Is there an easy way to constrain the rolling window by date range? For example, if an entity has Q1'11, Q2'11, Q4'11, Q1'12 (i.e. it's missing Q3'11), I don't want it to sum back to Q1'11.

Comment: @rgk Hmm... I am not aware of any way... if it's an essential requirement, you should consider opening another question. Andy Hayden is on now, and should be able to give you a good answer for that.

Comment: The docs for DataFrame.rolling imply that I can use a DateOffset (e.g. '4Q') and add a min_periods argument to ensure I have a full year but I keep getting a value error "window must be an integer". I think this open issue is related: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15969

Comment: @rgk Interesting... even I didn't know that!